# Transmitting AV signals one way

Tags: audio, wireless, video, video-transmitter

I have a video feed that's two AV cables (one sound, one video) and I'm looking to transmit them from the source to about 100-200 meters away. Specifically,  I need some sort of transmitter/receiver that I can work with. Are there any sort of circuits I can get that would work with what I need? What can I use for this? Or what *should* I use?

EDIT: I just want to clarify, I am not asking about a device that does everything for me, I was going to do the circuit I need myself as it's not too hard. I am asking about a transmitter that is appropriate for this kind of transmittion.

Comment: You can buy off-the-shelf video transmitter systems. Or you could use an off-the-shelf video player unit that connects over WiFi to a NAS.

Comment: Video, especially HD, has a huge amount of data in it.  You need a lot of bandwidth for that, or heavy compression. What kind of video are you using? HD? SD? Analog? Digital?

Comment: Analog SD with a normal AV (yellow/red) port.

Comment: Then maybe you could look at some old computer circuit diagrams? (such as things like the BBC Micro, Commodore 64, etc) They often use a small AV Modulator unit (silver box) to create an RF signal (often on Channel 36 by default). They first have to modulate the sound with the video though, so that would give you some clues to that.  Then it'd be a case of making an RF power amplifier to boost the signal and send it to an antenna.  A TV could then receive it. In fact, looking at the C64, the modulator they use has an audio input. http://ist.uwaterloo.ca/~schepers/MJK/pics/c64_front.gif

Comment: And this is the schematic for their modulator: http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/schematics/computers/c64/modulator-251025.gif

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking analog, and you don't mind compromising quality somewhat, and you're happy to run cable, one solution is to use baluns to ship the signals over two pairs of a cat5 cable.  This approach has some advantages over an RF link in that you have your own private transmission path (the cable) so there are no licensing, channel sharing, or interference issues, but it is almost guaranteed to be lower quality.  I've seen it done over about 250m of cat5 in a building's cabling, and the video was definitely degrading.  Nominal maximum distance for colour video is 300m.  You can buy the baluns separately and assemble them yourself, or you can find pre-assembled units with RCA and RJ45 sockets in a small box, one box at each end.

Another alternative, somewhat more expensive, higher quality, but with the potential for interference is wireless analog transmission, typically in the 2.4GHz band but depending on local licensing rules they might be available at any frequency that someone will sell them to you.